# get model id of model in nodeorm

Tags: node.js, node-orm2

With nodeorm2 (sqlite) in NodeJS, I "create" several models like this to fill the database of  my website with sample data:

```
req.models.myModel.create({
    'title' : 'Model title here',
    'content' : 'content here',
    'username' : 'username here'
}, callback_function);

req.models.myModel.create({
    'title' : 'Model 2 title here',
    'content' : 'content 2 here',
    'username' : 'other username'
}, callback_function);
```

These operations are asynchronous.
When they finish, I want to also add child models for the models that I just "created".

Relations between myModel and subModels are defined like this:

```
models.subModel.hasOne("parent", models.myModel, {
    "reverse" : "child"
});
```

How do I get the id of the models that I created, so that I can also add submodels?
I could use a 'find' to search the DB for the newly created models. However, it is not guaranteed that the models are created in the order that I specified.

In php/mysql I would use a mysql_insert_id() to achieve this. The equivalent in SQL would be last_insert_id().

EDIT:
in the callback function, I can access the id.

```
function callback_function(err, item){
    console.log(item.id);
}
```

However, this ID is the same for both callback functions. I don't understand it.
Even if I create separate callback functions with differently named attributes, the id is the same.

Comment: What module are you using to access the database?  There isn't a `nodeorm2` in NPM.

Comment: The module is called node-orm2. It can be installed with "npm install orm".